# Why am I getting JsonMappingException when setting values for hashset?

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, one-to-many, hashset

I have two POJO classes called A and B. The model classes are as below.

```
class A {
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "param")  
        private Set<B> params = new HashSet<>();
        // other attributes and getters and setters.....
    }

class B {
     @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="a_id")
        @JsonIgnore
        private A param;
         // other attributes and getters and setters.....

    }
```

I have written a rest controller method to persist entity A with B.
When I save the entity A, I want to save entity B also with that.

I am passing the below in my rest method body.

```
{
      "description": "test_des",
      "name": "test_name",  
      "params": [
        {     
          "name": "string",
          "text": "string",     
        }   
      ]
}
```

If I pass the above json my method works well, it saves the entity A in database and then entity B with the reference of entity A. But my problem is, I want to save more than one entities of B with A, for that I have to pass array of object as below.

```
{
      "description": "test_des",
      "name": "test_name",  
      "params": [
        {     
          "name": "string",
          "text": "string",     
        },
        {     
          "name": "string2",
          "text": "string2",     
        } 
      ]
}
```

This will give me an error saying,

```
"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
 Could not read document: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) 
 (through reference chain: com.a.model.A["params"]->java.util.HashSet[1]);
 nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
 (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.a.model.A["params"]->java.util.HashSet[1])"
```

What I am doing wrong? Please let me know.